# Unload and load in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There is a button in a sprite. I want to click that button and load menu.swf and unload the current swf. But only that sprite is removed, not the entire swf. What can I do?

```
go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader: ProLoader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF
var fl_ToLoad: Boolean = true;


function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (fl_ToLoad) {



        var x: Number = this.numChildren;
        while (x--) {
            this.removeChildAt(x);
        }



        fl_ProLoader = new ProLoader();
        fl_ProLoader.load(new URLRequest("menu.swf"));
        addChild(fl_ProLoader);
        fl_ProLoader.graphics.clear(); 
        fl_ProLoader.x = -245;
        fl_ProLoader.y = -140;
        fl_ProLoader.width = 600;
        fl_ProLoader.height = 850;
        fl_ProLoader.scaleX = 1
        fl_ProLoader.scaleY = 1
    } else {
        fl_ProLoader.unload();
        removeChild(fl_ProLoader);
        fl_ProLoader = null;

        for (var i: int = fl_ProLoader.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            fl_ProLoader.removeChildAt(i);

        }

    }
    // Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
    fl_ToLoad = !fl_ToLoad;
}
```

Comment: Because you address **this** instead of **root**. My guess is that **this** points to that sprite you're talking about.

Comment: If I replace "this" with root, I get the below error

Symbol 'sprite 90', Layer 'Actions', Frame 27, Line 23, Column 24 1119: Access of possibly undefined property numChildren through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
Symbol 'sprite 90', Layer 'Actions', Frame 27, Line 25, Column 9 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeChildAt through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Because **DisplayObject.root** is indeed typed as **DisplayObject** rather than **DisplayObjectContainer** with no regard to the actual class the **root** is instance of.

Comment: You need a reference to the swf (movieclip) that you want to unload. Unless... is the button you are clicking IN the swf you are trying to unload? If so, then this is not possible as you would be destroying the object while it is still executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer (root);
```

This gives you a reference to root cast to DisplayObjectContainer. You can now replace `this` with `rootContainer`

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at thenextfile_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()